# Unhandled promise rejection (evaluating 'result.offset')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am working with this external API it wont let me save an array, it keep crashing and sending this error

> Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'result.offset')]

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.retrieveData(true);
    var Airtable = require("airtable");
    var base = new Airtable({ apiKey: "xxxxxxxx" }).base(
      "ooooooooo"
    );
    var list = [];
    base("Hardware Display")
      .select({
        maxRecords: 99,
        view: "Grid view",
      })
      .eachPage(
        function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
          records.forEach(function (record) {
            console.log(record.get("Name"));
            list.push({
              label: record.get("Name"),
              value: record.get("Name"),
              key: record.get("Name"),
            });
          });
          fetchNextPage();
        },
        function done(err) {
          console.log("done");
          console.log("this.state.ATdisplays :", this.state.ATdisplays);
          console.log("list :", list);
          this.setState({ ATdisplays: list });
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
          }
        }
      );
  }
```

The issue is here

```
list.push({
              label: record.get("Name"),
              value: record.get("Name"),
              key: record.get("Name"),
            });
```

once i comment this everything smooth and it loop to the next page, I cant seems to save this array

I dont understand this problem

```
Stack trace:
  node_modules/airtable/node_modules/lodash/_baseIsEqual.js:22:6 in baseIsEqual
  node_modules/airtable/node_modules/lodash/_baseClone.js:29:14 in <global>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:194:17 in _callImmediatesPass
```

Comment: Replace the the 'problematic' portion with something static like `list.push({label: 'test'})`. This will show that the issue is either with the `.get` method or not. Setting an array of objects in state is 100% doable, so we know it's not that. My gut tells me that there's something to do with how the records are dealt with at the time of attempting to set the state.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was this variable, couldn't use inside promise so I replaced it with self

```
var self = this
self.setState({ ATdisplays: list });
```